# How can I get the full file path of an icon name?

Tags: python, gtk, icons, gnome

How can I get the full file path from an icon name in GNOME?

Comment: Is there something specific to icons in gnome? Use `os.path` services.

Comment: @khachik, there is indeed, gnome looks up an icon name in the current icon theme, which may be installed system-wide or per-user, so it is not predictable where the file may be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import gtk
icon_theme = gtk.icon_theme_get_default()
icon_info = icon_theme.lookup_icon("my-icon-name", 48, 0)
print icon_info.get_filename()
```

Answer (score 10):

Translation for Python 3:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()
icon_info = icon_theme.lookup_icon("my-icon-name", 48, 0)
print(icon_info.get_filename())
```

Comment: The second line should be `icon_theme = Gtk.IconTheme.get_default()` to be equivalent to the accepted answer (otherwise, the user's icon theme preference isn't taken into account).