# Loading the thumbnail inside an image file into a pixbuf

Tags: c, linux, gtk, gtk2, gdkpixbuf

Photos from cameras contain a thumbnail and the photo itself.  The thumbnail is created and used by the cameras to browse quickly without loading the full image.

I would like to mimic such behavior with C and Gtk+ 2.

Tools such as `exiftool` or `dcraw` can extract the thumbnail into a new file. However, I would like to load the thumbnail directly into a `GdkPixbuf` instead.

If there any function to extract the thumbnail already existing in photo and load it into `GdkPixbuf`?

Comment: I don't understand your question, are you getting the thumnail from the image file in the GTK code?

Comment: "the image file in the GTK code"??

Comment: No I understand less. How are you building your gtk app?

Comment: No, GTK+ does not have *its own* function to extract a thumbnail from an image file. GLib might, and GTK+ might use that in GtkFileChooserWidget; you can check the source of GtkFileChooserWidget on either GTK+ 2 or GTK+ 3 to see what it is. [Here's a hint.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34568727/getting-icon-based-on-mimetype-of-a-file-linux-python)

Comment: There is a discussion here: https://mail.gnome.org/archives/gtk-perl-list/2005-September/msg00071.html but I don't quite understand it because it uses Perl.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways but not an official™ one.

If you do not want to lose yourself in the EXIF details you can leverage [eog](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/EyeOfGnome) (Eye of GNOME): under the wood it is mainly [a C library](https://developer.gnome.org/eog/stable/).

Link your app to that library and call [eog_thumbnail_load](https://developer.gnome.org/eog/stable/eog-eog-thumbnail.html#eog-thumbnail-load) on your [EogImage](https://developer.gnome.org/eog/stable/eog-eog-image.html) object.

Comment: How can I link to this library?

Comment: On my system I'd use `gcc myapp.c -L/usr/lib/eog -leog $(pkg-config --cflags --libs eog)`.

Comment: Strangely enough on my computer I get an error that "Cannot find -leog". I'ce installed all the EOG related packages.

Comment: Well, you have to check where your distribution installs `libeog.so`. As you can see from the command line, mine puts it in `/usr/lib/eog/libeog.so`.

Answer (score 1):

No

The loading of images is via pixbuf loaders so if you have a nef or cr2, you have to provide a loader to handle these types of files

The way I have implemented this is to build my own pixbuf loader and use exiv2 to obtain the embedded preview image (a tif or jpg) and then let the standard pixbuf loaders load that

Comment: This would be my last resort because it produces latency and a lot of disk writing. Exiv2 uses libexiv2 which is a C++ library. There is a C wrapper for it called gexiv2 but it doesn't come with a documentation.

Comment: "produces a lot of disk writing" - I didn't remember seeing this in my strace output.  For your reference, here's the code for a gdk pixbuf loader using exiv2 - it doesn't like to load tifs from RAW file but for NEFs and CR2 straight out of camera, it works fine: [link]http://whatdoineed2do.blogspot.com/2016/02/custom-gdkpixbufloader-to-handle.html

Comment: Well if you want to go through and view some 200 photos you've taken then 200 JPG's have to be extracted and  written to the disk. Thanks for the link, I'll take a look.

Comment: The gdk pixbuf loader framework reads the original RAW file, providing chunks of data to the custom pixbuf loader.  The loader then has to keep all of this data in memory so there is NO write to disk (except for swapping of course).  When the framework completes reading and handing off the data to the loader, the actual pixbuf is then created from the in-memory cache of the RAW file.  In the case of the code I've linked, yes, its memory intensive since it buffers the entire RAW file (80MB for a D800 NEF) before using Exiv2 to extract the preview and giving it to the jpeg/tiff pixbuf to load